# using spark sql for conditional lag summation

Tags: pyspark

Below is the dataframe i have

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [("0", "0"), ("1", "2"), ("2", "3"), ("3", "4"), ("4", "0"), ("5", "5"), ("6", "5")],
    ["id", "value"])

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  0|    0|
|  1|    2|
|  2|    3|
|  3|    4|
|  4|    0|
|  5|    5|
|  6|    5|
+---+-----+
```

And what I want to get is :

```
+---+-----+---+-----+
| id|value|masterid|partsum|
+---+-----|---+-----+
|  0|    0|  0|    0| 
|  1|    2|  0|    2|
|  2|    3|  0|    5|
|  3|    4|  0|    9|
|  4|    0|  4|    0|
|  5|    5|  4|    5|
|  6|    5|  4|   10|
+---+-----+---+-----+
```

So I try to use SparkSQL to do so:

```
df=df.withColumn("masterid", F.when( df.value !=0 , F.lag(df.id)).otherwise(df.id))
```

I original thought the lag function can help me process before next iteration so as to get the masterid col. Unfortunately, after i check the manual , it cant help.

So , i would like to ask if there are any special functions i could use to do what i want? Or is there any "conditional lag" function i could use? so that, when i see non-zero item, i can use lag until find a zero number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try defining a sub-group label (`g` in the below code) and two Window Specs:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w1 = Window.orderBy('id')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('g').orderBy('id')

df.withColumn('g', F.sum(F.expr('if(value=0,1,0)')).over(w1)).select(
    'id'
  , 'value'
  , F.first('id').over(w2).alias('masterid')
  , F.sum('value').over(w2).alias('partsum')
).show()
#+---+-----+--------+-------+
#| id|value|masterid|partsum|
#+---+-----+--------+-------+
#|  0|    0|       0|    0.0|
#|  1|    2|       0|    2.0|
#|  2|    3|       0|    5.0|
#|  3|    4|       0|    9.0|
#|  4|    0|       4|    0.0|
#|  5|    5|       4|    5.0|
#|  6|    5|       4|   10.0|
#+---+-----+--------+-------+
```